# Can you use a static method as default parameter in __init__ in python classes?

Tags: python, oop, static-methods

I am writing a class for a neural network and I want to give it some form of customization, so that you can choose different cost functions and regularizations. For this I want to set them as default parameters in the `__init__()` method.
But when I pass `MyClass.static_method` in my example, the Interpreter then tells me that MyClass is not (yet) defined. Why is this and is there a nicer workaround than mine?

You can of course just set the static method as a default parameter, but then other problems arise. For example, if I want to access the functions name (which I actually want), I cannot use `__name__` rightaway. I know how to do it another way, by accessing `static_method.__func__.__name__`. But this seems clumsy and as you get a staticmethod object, seems like its not intended to be used this way.

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        do_something()

    def __init__(self, func=MyClass.static_method, func2=static_method):
        self.name = func.__name__                  #Does not work
        self.name2 = func2.__func__.__name__       #Should work
```

I did expect for the `MyClass.static_method` to work, but the class does not seem to exist then. So, one last time, why?

Comment: Static methods are rarely used in Python, simply because they can and should be functions. Making your static method a function (defined or imported before the class) should also solve your problem.

Comment: static methods are not that uncommon ... and there are lots of use cases that they are appropriate for ... and i dont really see how it not being a static method resolves the issue exactly

Comment: @JoranBeasley In many years of Python coding I learn 2 cases where it *could* be useful, 0 where it *should* be done, and one cause *why* it is done so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're having problems with your static method usage as a default argument is due to a combination of two issues.

The first issue is that the default argument needs to be well defined when the `def` statement is run, not only when the function is called. That's because the default argument gets built into the function object, rather than being recalculated each time the function runs (this is the same reason why a mutable default argument like an empty list is often an error). Anyway, this is why you can't use `MyClass.static_method` as the default argument, since `MyClass` isn't defined yet when the function is being defined (the class object is only made after all its contents have been created).

The next issue is that a `staticmethod` object doesn't have all the same attributes and methods as a regular function. Normally this doesn't matter, as when you access it through a class object (e.g. `MyClass.static_method` once `MyClass` exists) or through an instance (e.g. `self.static_method`), it will be callable and have a `__name__`. But that's because you get the underlying function in those situations, rather than the `staticmethod` object itself. The `staticmethod` object itself is a descriptor, but not a callable.

So neither of these functions will work correctly:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        pass

    def foo(self, func=MyClass.static_method): # won't work because MyClass doesn't exist yet
        pass

    def bar(self, func=static_method): # this declaration will work (if you comment out foo)
        name = func.__name__  # but this doesn't work when the bar() is called
        func()                # nor this, as func is the staticmethod object
```

What does work would be to use the actual function underlying the `staticmethod` object as the default:

```
    def baz(self, func=static_method.__func__):  # this works!
        name = func.__name__
        func()
```

This also works when you pass in some other function (or bound method), unlike the version of your code that used `name = func.__func__.__name__`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DEFAULT = object()
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        do_something()

    def __init__(self, func=DEFAULT, func2=DEFAULT):
        self.name = self.static_method.__name__  if func is DEFAULT else func.__name__
        self.name2 = self.static_method.__func__.__name__ if func2 is DEFAULT else func2.__func__.__name__
```

I guess??

Comment: Viable Idea, though @Blckknght 's answer explained the underlying problem. +1 though